# Ansible write variables into YAML file

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2, ansible

I have a specific ansible variable structure that I want to get from the vault into a yaml file on my hosts.

Lets assume a structure like this:

```
secrets:
   psp1:
     username: this
     password: that
   secret_key: 123
  ...
```

I need something like a "generic" template to output whatever "secrets" contains at the moment, since the content changes almost completely based on the current environment.

The easiest solution I can think of is to output the whole structure in an template like this:

```
# config/secrets.yml
{{ secrets | to_yaml }}
```

But the jinja2 to_yaml filter does only "yamlify" the first level, deeper nestings are outputted in json.

Can I work around that problem somehow? Is there an easier way to achieve what I want?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: JSON is a valid subset of YAML, so you're still getting YAML.

Comment: @jwodder Arg! Of course you're right. I don't know why I always overlook this fact. Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. As jwodder said, it's valid.
2. If you're using `to_yaml` (instead of `to_nice_yaml`) you have fairly old install of ansible, it's time to upgrade.
3. Use `to_nice_yaml`
4. It's possible to pass your own kwargs to filter functions, which usually pass them on to underlying python module call. Like [this one](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L57) for your case. So something like:

```
{{ secrets | to_nice_yaml( width=50, explicit_start=True, explicit_end=True) }}
```

only catch is you can't override <s>indent=4,</s>* `allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False`

* Note that `indent` can now be overridden, at least as of Ansible 2.2.0 (I use it to indent 2 spaces to follow coding standards for one project).

Better documentation for `to_nice_yaml` can be found [here](https://dpinte.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/pyaml-dump-option/).

Comment: this worked out great for my playbook for elasticsearch, dumped the entire config from an array

Comment: It's not a formatting bug, it's a markdown feature. Code inside a list item has to be double-indented.

Comment: Note that `indent` can now be overridden, at least as of Ansible 2.2.0 (I use it to indent 2 spaces to follow coding standards for one project). See: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/17085

Comment: @Kashyap Where did you get to_nice_yaml options documentation?

Comment: @EnzoR from code, not documentation. But sure if they updated it in last 4 years.

Comment: What about default_style and friends? Do I really need to get to the source code? Which files were you reading?

Comment: @EnzoR, it's here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.12/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L57, and this seems to be the fix for indent: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/27d065924f5a5318db4ecb52ec695cf1e4de7293