# How do I pretty print an object in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to pretty print a registered object in ansible to help with debugging.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use with_dict and var= in your debug statement:

```
- tasks: 
  - name: build web node
    nova_compute:
    arguments: xyz
    register: os_web_node
  - debug: var={{ item }}
    with_dict: os_web_node
```

Comment: Need to use jinja2 template around variable used with_dict otherwise it throws error "with_dict expects a dict".

example:
 - debug: var={{ item }}
    with_dict: "{{ os_web_node }}"

Answer (score 21):

You also have [`to_nice_yaml` and `to_nice_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) if you want to control the format itself. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963751/ansible-write-variables-into-yaml-file/28969144#28969144).